# PyTorch CUDA : the provided PTX was compiled with an unsupported toolchain

Tags: pytorch, cuda, ptx

I am using Nvidia V100 with the following specs:

```bash
(pytorch) [s.1915438@cl1 aneurysm]$ srun nvidia-smi
Sun Jul 17 16:17:27 2022       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 495.29.05    Driver Version: 495.29.05    CUDA Version: 11.5     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla V100-PCIE...  On   | 00000000:D8:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   31C    P0    25W / 250W |      0MiB / 16160MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The Python, Pytorch and CUDA version is as follows:

```bash
Python 3.8.13 (default, Mar 28 2022, 11:38:47) 
[GCC 7.5.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
>>> torch.__version__
'1.12.0+cu113'
```

When I run a python file, containing a machine learning model, I get the following error.

```bash
(pytorch) [s.1915438@cl1 aneurysm]$ srun python aneurysm.py
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  the provided PTX was compiled with an unsupported toolchain.
srun: error: ccs2114: task 0: Aborted
```

Is it some kind of compatibility issue? Should I fallback to CUDA 10
.2 as the V100 is very old GPU?

Comment: Update your GPU driver to the latest one available for your GPU.

Comment: did you notice I am using `srun`? I am on a HPC cluster.

Comment: And that changes things how, exactly? The driver doesn't support the PTX that Pytorch is generating. If you want to run that particular code, the cluster node needs a driver upgrade. If that isn't possible you are our of luck

Comment: thanks for the clarification, I guess I am out of luck here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone using an old GPU from an HPC cluster is probably out of luck. In my case, I had Nvidia Driver 495 which is not very old. In fact, for CUDA 11.5 [they recommend](https://www.nvidia.co.uk/Download/driverResults.aspx/188588/en-uk) Nvidia Driver 470.

This is the [official reply](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/provided-ptx-was-compiled-with-an-unsupported-toolchain-error-using-cub/168292) from Nvidia for a similar problem. They also recommend updating the driver. And most of the time HPC centres won't update the driver on personal requests.

Answer (score 0):

you can use cuda-compat package as described in the [cuda-compatibility docs](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/cuda-compatibility/index.html#cuda-application-compatibility%5B/url%5D)

1. download the latest cuda-compat package from [cuda repo](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/)
2. install it or extract it
3. import it before running codes by

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/cuda/compat/so/files:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

4. magic~

BTW: nvidia only enable this feature for data-center series for commercial interest but technically Nvidia could bring this feature to all devices.